# Spring Data JPA adding exception to Cascading

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, cascade

In my application, I have to add functionality where a user can be removed from database. My users can have up to three roles (it's a Set) - USER, EDITOR and ADMIN. There are few types of Users, but all of them extend AbstractUser class. Here it is:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class AbstractUser extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Because of CascadeType.ALL, when I want to remove a user i get IntegrityViolationException, because the program wants to remove a Role entity along with deleted user and of course, it can't happen:

```
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKJULYW7FW6N9F67QYIID41SEP6: PUBLIC.USER_ROLE FOREIGN KEY(ROLES_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ROLE(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
delete from role where id=? and version=? [23503-197]
```

This thing is very easy to bypass using setRoles to the user with empty Set, so here is how it works like right now:

```
    @Test
    public void userRemovalThrowsNoException() {
        User user = userRepository.findById(6L).get();
        user.setRoles(Collections.emptySet());
        userRepository.save(user);
        userRepository.delete(user);
    }
```

This way works, but it's far from ideal, I think retrieving User entity from repository, setting its Roles to empty Set, then updating it in database just to use `delete()` method after is too much of redundant code. My question is, what would be the most efficient way to delete User entity without doing unnecessary operations?

Comment: So why do you have a `Cascade.ALL` on the relationship, when you don't want to cascade deletes?

Comment: I don't think the Cascade.ALL is obligatory, but I'm not the only person who wrote the app. What I want to know is if there is a way to somehow bypass it just for this one case so I'm 100% sure the rest of the code stays intact. All test cases end with success, but I want to know if there's any good alternative to what I wrote, just for "educational purposes".